# Check if "Fast Web View" property is enabled on a PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am writing some integration tests to verify the correctness of convert to PDF operations. On one of the test I would like to check if a PDF has "Fast Web View" enabled. I though this would be a straight forward test, however I don't find any property which provides that information. I am using iTextShap and writing my tests C#.

Since code always helps to visualize the problem, below is a simple example of what I am trying to do

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ValidationTools
{
    public class PDFValidator
    {
        readonly PdfReader _readerInstance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor taking a path to a PDF as string
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pdfPath"></param>
        public PDFValidator(string pdfPath)
        {
            _readerInstance = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
        }

        //THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO
        public bool VerifyIfFastWebViewIsEnabled() {
            return (bool)_readerInstance["FASTWEBVIEW"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: iText doesn't support linearized PDFs, nor is it on their development roadmap: http://support.itextpdf.com/node/142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter mentioned, based on [the iText forum](http://support.itextpdf.com/node/142), iText does not directly support any "linearized PDF" (a.k.a "Fast Web View") features directly, and therefore does not say whether PDFs are linearized or not.

That said, you can look at [the PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) Annex F (starting from page 675) and use the information described there to implement your own check for whether the PDF is linearized or not.

According to this spec, the token `/Linearized` should appear near the beginning of the file - all you have to do is check whether it is present or not.